# В книге Thinking in Java 4th Edition дана программа, которая должна работать корректно, но мой код выбросил исключение. Почему?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, lock

В  книге Thinking in Java 4th Edition дана программа, которая должна работать корректно, но несмотря на это при запуске ExplicitCriticalSection.main() выбросилось исключение. Почему?

Вот код предложенный автором книги:

```
package concurrency;
//: concurrency/ExplicitCriticalSection.java
// Using explicit Lock objects to create critical sections.
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

// Synchronize the entire method:
class ExplicitPairManager1 extends PairManager {
  private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  public synchronized void increment() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      p.incrementX();
      p.incrementY();
      store(getPair());
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}

// Use a critical section:
class ExplicitPairManager2 extends PairManager {
  private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  public void increment() {
    Pair temp;
    lock.lock();
    try {
      p.incrementX();
      p.incrementY();
      temp = getPair();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
    store(temp);
  }
}

public class ExplicitCriticalSection {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PairManager
      pman1 = new ExplicitPairManager1(),
      pman2 = new ExplicitPairManager2();
    CriticalSection.testApproaches(pman1, pman2);
  }
} /* Output: (Sample)
pm1: Pair: x: 15, y: 15 checkCounter = 174035
pm2: Pair: x: 16, y: 16 checkCounter = 2608588
*///:~
```

---

```
//: concurrency/CriticalSection.java
// Synchronizing blocks instead of entire methods. Also
// demonstrates protection of a non-thread-safe class
// with a thread-safe one.
package concurrency;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.*;

class Pair { // Not thread-safe
  private int x, y;
  public Pair(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  public Pair() { this(0, 0); }
  public int getX() { return x; }
  public int getY() { return y; }
  public void incrementX() { x++; }
  public void incrementY() { y++; }
  public String toString() {
    return "x: " + x + ", y: " + y;
  }
  public class PairValuesNotEqualException extends RuntimeException {
    public PairValuesNotEqualException() {
      super("Pair values not equal: " + Pair.this);
    }
  }
  // Arbitrary invariant -- both variables must be equal:
  public void checkState() {
    if(x != y)
      throw new PairValuesNotEqualException();
  }
}

// Protect a Pair inside a thread-safe class:
abstract class PairManager {
  AtomicLong checkCounter = new AtomicLong(0);
  protected Pair p = new Pair();
  private List<Pair> storage = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Pair>());
  public synchronized Pair getPair() {
    // Make a copy to keep the original safe:
    return new Pair(p.getX(), p.getY());
  }
  // Assume this is a time consuming operation
  protected void store(Pair p) {
    storage.add(p);
    try {
      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
    } catch(InterruptedException ignore) {}
  }
  public abstract void increment();
}

// Synchronize the entire method:
class PairManager1 extends PairManager {
  public synchronized void increment() {
    p.incrementX();
    p.incrementY();
    store(getPair());
  }
}

// Use a critical section:
class PairManager2 extends PairManager {
  public void increment() {
    Pair temp;
    synchronized(this) {
      p.incrementX();
      p.incrementY();
      temp = getPair();
    }
    store(temp);
  }
}

class PairManipulator implements Runnable {
  private PairManager pm;
  public PairManipulator(PairManager pm) {
    this.pm = pm;
  }
  public void run() {
    while(true)
      pm.increment();
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "Pair: " + pm.getPair() +
      " checkCounter = " + pm.checkCounter.get();
  }
}

class PairChecker implements Runnable {
  private PairManager pm;
  public PairChecker(PairManager pm) {
    this.pm = pm;
  }
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      pm.checkCounter.incrementAndGet();
      pm.getPair().checkState();
    }
  }
}

public class CriticalSection {
  // Test the two different approaches:
  static void testApproaches(PairManager pman1, PairManager pman2) {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    PairManipulator
      pm1 = new PairManipulator(pman1),
      pm2 = new PairManipulator(pman2);
    PairChecker
      pcheck1 = new PairChecker(pman1),
      pcheck2 = new PairChecker(pman2);
    exec.execute(pm1);
    exec.execute(pm2);
    exec.execute(pcheck1);
    exec.execute(pcheck2);
    try {
      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Sleep interrupted");
    }
    System.out.println("pm1: " + pm1 + "\npm2: " + pm2);
    System.exit(0);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PairManager
      pman1 = new PairManager1(),
      pman2 = new PairManager2();
    testApproaches(pman1, pman2);
  }
} /* Output: (Sample)
pm1: Pair: x: 15, y: 15 checkCounter = 272565
pm2: Pair: x: 16, y: 16 checkCounter = 3956974
*///:~
```

Результат работы при запуске на моем устройстве:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-4" concurrency.Pair$PairValuesNotEqualException: Pair values not equal: x: 2, y: 1
    at concurrency.Pair.checkState(CriticalSection.java:32)
    at concurrency.PairChecker.run(CriticalSection.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
pm1: Pair: x: 393, y: 393 checkCounter = 3
pm2: Pair: x: 394, y: 394 checkCounter = 4934633
```

Comment: Есть такой ответ, но он мне показался недостаточно понятным:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995294/critical-sections-thinking-in-java-example

Comment: Я предполагаю, что нельзя в одном объекте для синхронизации одновременно использовать два способа: интерфейс Lock и ключевое слово synchronized; потому что их блокировки не синхронизированы между собой. В интернете подтверждения этому я не нашел, поэтому только предполагаю.